# Generate one-time-pad with pre-shared key and public randomness

Tags: symmetric, one-time-pad, perfect-secrecy

I know very little about cryptography, so I apologize if the question does not make sense.

Let's say we design a function $F(P, X) \rightarrow K$ that takes in a pre-shared private key $P$ and a publicly available source of randomness (say a server that generates true random numbers) $X$. The output $K$ of this function is a new key that we use as a one-time-pad to encrypt and decrypt a message.

The sender pre-share the key $P$, the function $F$ and the source of randomness to the receiver before their communication. For every new message $M$, the sender collects the random information $X$, generates a one-time-pad $K$ using the function $F$ and encrypts the message with $K$. The receiver generates the same $K$ and decrypts the message.

My questions are

1. This scheme is not information theoretic secure, right? because AFAIK, the one-time-pad cannot be reused in any way, but in this case, we are reusing $P$ for every message, which can be considered as part of the one-time-pad $K$
2. Is this scheme viable? Is it more secure than simply encrypting/decrypting with the pre-shared key $P$?

Comment: @kelalaka Sorry for the ambiguity. By "privately send" I mean "pre-share", like the private key used in symmetric encryption.

Comment: @kelalaka Kerckhoffs, not Kirchhoff.

Comment: Re. 2nd. para: Is the definition of $F$ correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question says "pre-shared private key" where it means: pre-shared *secret* key. We use *private* key for asymmetric cryptography only, and the private key is usually not shared (only the matching public key is shared).

> This scheme is not information theoretic secure, right?

It is not, for the reason stated. Enough known plaintext and enumerating all the possible $P$ is enough to break it for an arbitrarily powerful adversary.

> Is this scheme viable?

Sort of, for appropriate $F$ and source of shared randomness $X$. But there are serious practical issues:

- $X$ must be wide enough to make accidental repeat use of $X$ impossible (creating a duplicate $K$, allowing decryption when the first $K$ is used to encipher known plaintext, or when both $K$ are used to encipher non-random plaintext).
- $X$ must be available and in sync for sender and receiver.
- Adversaries must be unable to chose or influence $X$ (if an adversary could force $X$ to be a constant or belong to a small set, that allows attack).

However all this is fixable by making $X$ a public counter rather than random. $X$ is transmitted in clear at start of the message: that's the Initialization Vector. This practice is called [Counter Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_(CTR)) when $F$ is a block cipher. The IV can be kept by the sender, or drawn randomly in whole or part for each new message.

Answer (score 4):

You can relate your construction to the approach of using a [pesudo-random function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_function_family) (PRF) in order to extend the key-length on the one-time-pad construction (in fact, it is more typicall to use a [pseudo-random generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_generator) (PRG), but since this can be obtained from a PRF, and since your construction resembles more a PRF as well, I prefer to present it like this).

A PRF is a family of functions that resemble random functions, in a very precise way.
We say that a family of functions $\{F_s\}_{s\in \{0,1\}^\ell}$ is *pseudo-random*, where $F_s:\{0,1\}^n\to\{0,1\}^m$, if a function sampled at random from this set (which is done by sampling a random $s\in\{0,1\}^\ell$) is indistinguishable from a totally random function $f:\{0,1\}^n\to\{0,1\}^m$ (i.e. one were the image of each $x\in\{0,1\}^n$ is a uniformly random string in $\{0,1\}^m$).
If you have such a family of functions then you can build an "extension" of the OTP by simply using the pre-shared secret key $s$ as a seed to get a random function $F_s$, and using $F_s(0)\|F_s(1)\|\cdots\|F_s(N)$ as a (much longer) OTP key.

Now, if you think about it, when you consider your function $F(P,X)\to K$ you're sort of using this idea: you are using some shared secret randomness to expand it to a longer, perhaps not totally uniform key.
So, to answer your questions, your scheme is not information-theoretic secure but not really because you're reusing the key, but because the PRF is not really information-theoretic secure.

**Remarks**

Notice that, in particular, the source of randomness you call $P$ doesn't even need to be random! It only needs to ensure that the same value of $P$ is not reused among several different encryptions, and this can be achieved via a counter as I illustrate above. There is some randomness involved of course, but this is coming from the shared key.